# Recycler view hiding the data below it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I have a layout with recycler view and a footer below recycler view. If my list has few elements the footer was visible but if I inflate a lot of data in recycler view my layout(footer) below it was not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="bk.tillster.com.activities.CheckOutActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_check_out">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_more_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/box_with_borders"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/credit_card_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/credit_card_vertical_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/add_items_button"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/order_menu_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/add_more_items"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/credit_card_vertical_margin"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/checkout_content"
        layout="@layout/checkout_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/order_menu_list_view"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the footer looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/credit_card_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/credit_card_vertical_margin">

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:weightSum="1">

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                      android:layout_gravity="start"
                      android:layout_weight="0.5"
                      android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/credit_card"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/my_card"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="end"
                      android:layout_weight="0.3"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                      android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/tax_applied"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="end"
                      android:layout_weight="0.2"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                      android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:hint="***"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:hint="***"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/place_order"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I think I can divide the layouts into fragments and inflate them dynamically but I want to do them with in an activity. And also want to know the reason as why the recycler view is populating on top of the footer. Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I'm trying to achieve something similar to Starbucks checkout page. Attached screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGYzb.png)

Comment: In @MinFu code remove this line "android:layout_below="@+id/order_menu_list_view"" from include tag  and try again.

Comment: Instead of     android:layout_height="wrap_content" I gave footer height as 150dp and that actually solved the problem

Comment: Ok, that's is great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want your footer scrollable with your recyclerview? if not below may works for you:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/order_menu_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_more_items"
    android:layout_above="@+id/checkout_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/credit_card_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/checkout_content"
    layout="@layout/checkout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

Comment: No, I don't want my footer to be scrollable and this one giving me circular dependency exception. I edited my question to give you an understanding what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @MinFu In Include tag you have to remove this line "android:layout_below="@+id/order_menu_list_view"" else it will throw circular dependency exception